# Use CSS (or JavaScript) instead of SMIL

Tags: javascript, html, css, svg, smil

I see the following alert in my chrome console:

```
SVG's SMIL animations (<animate>, <set>, etc.) are deprecated and will be removed. Please use CSS animations or Web animations instead.
```

**So I want to replace SMIL with CSS.**
There are a few things what I can do in CSS, but I don't know how to do this one.
My problem is that **I animated d attribute in SMIL and I don't know that can I / how can I do it in CSS.**
Here is my code:

```css
svg{
 position: fixed;
}
```

```html
<svg width="500" height="500" viewBox="0 0 500 500">
 <path id="rect" fill="lightblue" d="M10 10 L30 10 L30 30 L10 30 Z"/>
 <animate xlink:href="#rect"
  attributeName="d"
  attributeType="XML"
  values="M20 20 L30 20 L40 40 L20 40 Z;
  M10 10 L30 10 L40 30 L10 40 Z;
  M10 10 L30 10 L30 30 L10 30 Z;
  M20 20 L30 20 L40 40 L20 40 Z"
  begin="0s"
  dur="2s" 
  repeatCount="indefinite"
 />
</svg>
```

Thank you!

P.S.: If it is not possible in CSS or faster in JavaScript, JavaScript would be good too.

Comment: It's not currently possible in CSS. Its pretty hard in javascript as you'd have to implement an interpolation engine.

Comment: Which interpolation engine do you recommend? (I only need to do animation with the d attribute)

Comment: when I wrote *implement* I meant you'd have to write one yourself.

Comment: As Robert has already mentioned animating co-ordinates is not possible with CSS but the end output can be achieved using CSS animation. However doing this for multiple such path elements with different dimensions would be too much effort. If it is only for this one then I can suggest a CSS approach.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I wrote a some JavaScript to interpolate between paths. It is very easy to use. You just add the script to your page and write the following lines:

```
var rect = new bigT('#rect');
rect.indefinite(true)
        .easing("linear")
        .duration(2000)
        .setPathKeyframes(
        "M20 20 L30 20 L40 40 L20 40 Z",
        "M10 10 L30 10 L40 30 L10 40 Z",
        "M10 10 L30 10 L30 30 L10 30 Z",
        "M20 20 L30 20 L40 40 L20 40 Z");
rect.startAnimation();
```

You can download here [bigT.js](https://s3.amazonaws.com/finely/resources/bigT.js)

Also, here is a preview with your svg: http://jsfiddle.net/r99fkndq/3/

Alternatively, you can use a more extensive library like D3.js.